# How large is the Nanking Cherry seed?

Tags: cherries

I've looked all over the internet, and can't seem to find any Nanking Cherry seed images. Can someone please post one?

I'm considering one as a gift since it's not invasive, and easy to maintain.

Comment: http://georgeweigel.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/reich.picking.nanking.cherries.jpg

Comment: You're giving someone a _cherry seed_? Not a _cherry plant_, a _cherry seed_?

Comment: @Stephie yep, but the seeds.

Comment: @NiallC. I'm looking at giving them a cherry bush.

Comment: [This](https://www.google.com/search?q=Nanking+cherry+seeds&newwindow=1&safe=active&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjR9amJ1a3NAhVBUVIKHWL1A3oQ_AUICSgC&biw=1366&bih=628) is a link to images of the seeds.

Comment: So all of the cherries are nanking cherry?